# Adding different css in collapsibles in ReactJS?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have used 'react-collapsible' library to implement collapsible feature.

```
<Collapsible trigger = "MyData" className = "addcss" >
  <p>I am the content.<p>
<Collapsible />
```

I need to style the header-MyData when it's clicked differently inside a css. I tried with .collapsible__trigger but it changes the view for both.
I need to change css for .collapse__trigger isopen. 
How do I do that? 
Thanks!

Comment: If you are willing to use material UI then you can refer this : https://material-ui.com/components/expansion-panels/

Comment: Thanks for adding this on! Will incorporate this too.
I used .collapsible__trigger.is-open and .collapsible__trigger.is-closed to style it.

Comment: using material UI will not only help you in desktop it also helps for portable devices too.